# In jQuery sortable dynamic input fields, after selection of jQuery autocomplete, show the label, not the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

With jQuery, I have made an `Add new filed` button, that adds an input field on click. I also have assigned `autocomplete` for the input field.

But the problem is, autocomplete is working only for the first field, not for the dynamically added fields. And also, after selecting any of the options, how can I show the label of the option, not its value?

I have been looking for the way of solving this problem for a while, but have not got the correct explanation. It'll be very helpful if you can suggest me how this can be solved. Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
         var $originals = tr.children();
         var $helper = tr.clone();
         $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
         });
         return $helper;
      },
      updateIndex = function() {
         $('td.index').each(function(i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
         });
      };
   $("#sort tbody").sortable({
      helper: fixHelperModified,
      stop: updateIndex
   }).disableSelection();
   $("#addNew").click(function() {
      $('#add').append("<tr class='rem'><td class='index'>1</td><td><input id='author-search'><button class='delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
      updateIndex();
   });
   $("body").on('click', '#add .delete', function() {
      $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
      updateIndex();
   });
});
$("#author-search").autocomplete({
   source: [{
      label: "Tom Smith",
      value: "1234"
   }, {
      label: "Tommy Smith",
      value: "12321"
   }],
   minLength: 3,
   select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).val(ui.item.value);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="sort" class="grid">
    <button id='addNew'>Add new field</button>
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="index">No.</th><th>Author</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="add">
        <tr class="rem"><td class="index">1</td><td><input id="author-search"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all you can't repeat ID's in a  page, they are unique by definition.

As for the autocomplete you need to call that plugin on any new inputs you add.

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for the response, it's getting clear but how can prevent the label to be changed into its value after selection?

Comment: set label instead of value in `select`? ...`$(this).val(ui.item.label);`?

Comment: Is is possible to keep the label in the input field and use their value? Because I need to use the values in other places, not the labels. @charlietfl

Comment: can store the whole object as data on the element if you want....`$(this).data('selected', ui.item)`

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could suggest an example. Thanks. @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on your code. This makes unique IDs and applies Autocomplete to each new field.

```js
$(function() {
  var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
      var $originals = tr.children();
      var $helper = tr.clone();
      $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
      });
      return $helper;
    },
    updateIndex = function() {
      $('td.index').each(function(i) {
        $(this).html(i + 1);
      });
    },
    makeAutocomplete = function($item) {
      $item.autocomplete({
        source: [{
          label: "Tom Smith",
          value: "1234"
        }, {
          label: "Tommy Smith",
          value: "12321"
        }],
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $item.val(ui.item.value);
        }
      });
    };

  $("#sort-1 tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
  }).disableSelection();
  $("#addNew-1").click(function() {
    var c = $("#add tr").length;
    c++;
    $('#add').append("<tr class='rem'><td class='index'>" + c + "</td><td><input id='author-search-" + c + "'><button class='delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
    updateIndex();
    makeAutocomplete($("#author-search-" + c));
  });
  $("body").on('click', '#add .delete', function() {
    $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
    updateIndex();
  });
  
  makeAutocomplete($("#author-search-1"));

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="sort-1" class="grid">
  <button id='addNew-1'>Add new field</button>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="index">No.</th>
      <th>Author</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="add">
    <tr class="rem">
      <td class="index">1</td>
      <td><input id="author-search-1"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```